# Proving the smoothness (indefinitely differentiability) of $2 \cos^{-1}(1-x)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I am trying to prove that $\frac{d^n\theta}{dx^n}$ where $x = 1-\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ exists $\forall n > 0$. I found that $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{2}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$ and based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1142794/424081) I think I only need to prove that $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ is smooth (notice is a function of $\theta$ and its firsts derivatives looks like fun).

I also found that $\cos^{-1}(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{1+2k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}{k!+2kk!}$ (at [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor%20series%20arc%20cos%20x)). But I am not sure that the existence of its Taylor Series implies its smoothness. I thought that by linearity of differentiation and because all terms in the series are polynomials (smooth funcions) there could be a way to make it work.

Is there a simple (elegant) way to prove its smoothness? Until now my only approach is to find a pattern of the n-th derivative, however I am actively trying to avoid that because of [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%20n-th%20derivative%20arc%20cos(1-x)%20n%3D1..10).

**edit:**
I am trying to prove that $\theta = 2 \cos^{-1}(1-x)$ is smooth (in other words, has infinitely many derivatives $\exists \frac{d^n\theta}{dx^n}\, \forall n>0$)

I tried different approaches, but based on the Taylor Expansion of $\cos^{-1}$ I found that $\theta = 2 \cos^{-1}(1-x)$ can be expressed by polynomials (which are smooth functions) and therefore its derivatives.

I have never worked with Taylor Series, so I am not really confident about this last statement.

**Side note:** My original expression was $x=1-\cos\frac{\theta}{2},\, -1 \le x \le 1$ (which implies $\theta = 2 \cos^{-1}(1-x)$) and because of that I derived $\frac{d\theta}{dx} = \frac{2}{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$ applying $\frac{d}{dx}$ to both sides.

Comment: I can't see what your title has to do with the body of the question.

Comment: Well from $x=1-\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ I get $\theta = 2\cos^{-1}(1-x)$ which is the function I am working with.

Comment: I have read three times your question and I cannot understand what you are asking. Can you please edit and make it clear at least what function it is that you want to prove smoothness? Also: the body of the question has to be comprehensible independently of the title.

Comment: You can't used the Taylor series to show that the function is smooth because  for the Taylor series even to exist at one point the function has to have infinitely many derivatives there...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $y = f(x)$ and $x = f^{-1}(y)$, you have:
$$x^\prime(y)=\frac{dx}{dy}(y)=\left(f^{-1}\right)^\prime(y)=\frac{1}{f^\prime(f^{-1}(y))}=\frac{1}{f^\prime \circ f^{-1}(y)}.$$

You can use [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2607704/show-that-g-circ-f-is-n-times-differentiable) to understand the proof that if $f,g$ are smooth then $g \circ f$ is also smooth.

Then if $f$ is smooth and never vanishing, $1/f$ is also smooth.

Finally $x(y)$ is a function composition of functions describe above, hence is smooth.

*This doesn't provide you with a closed for the derivatives of $f$, but at least proves that $x(y)$ is smooth which was your question.*

Comment: Smooth in the question means *has infinitely many derivatives* not just one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I understand that. If you read the post I linked, you’ll see that it deals with infinitely many derivatives and not only the first one. Induction has to be used here.